# how to access the bean from frontend to backend module in java

Tags: java, spring

I have two module back end which contains all the spring implementation and dao implementation and i have other module frontend contains the jsp and html now i want to access the initialized bean of the backend from frontend.Please suggest the way if any one can help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can access backend-beans if they are in same JVM.  You can import the backend spring-configuration into the frontend-configuration (or by doing component scan if it's annotation driven). By doing this, those beans are simply available in front-end.  (You can do this only if all the beans are in same JVM)

Comment: yes they are in same jvm and could you please suggest any site where i can see the code and its implementation.Thanks in advance.